# How parse the HTML data using tag name or id in iOS

Tags: html, ios

In the paring use Kanna (old Swift-HTML-Parser), Fuzi, happle, NDHpple but unable to get direct tag or id without using root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the tag name of your HTML data you want to parse and then start your query of parsing corresponding to that tag only.